# How Can I Split string every nth character, And Display like This?

Tags: python, string, split, width, alphabet

I want to print the following string:

```
1234567890
```

as follows:

```
123
456
789
0
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = '1234567890'
output = '\n'.join(re.findall(r'.{1,3}', inp))
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
123
456
789
0
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
x = "1234567890"
n = 3

y = list([x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x), n)])

for chunk in y:
    print(chunk)
```